# F# and Excel vba

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, excel-dna, fsharp.data.sqlclient

I have written a function in F# which basically gets data from an access db and performs various computations. Is there a way to call this function from excel vba?I want to pass on all parameter values via excel and also get all the output values in excel. what would be the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: well there is [Tsunami](http://tsunami.io/download.html) / [FCell](http://fcell.io/) - no need for VBA :D

Comment: You could also checkout Excel DNA. You can find some examples using it with F# [here](http://excel-dna.net/tag/f/).

Comment: If you publish the F# function as an Excel-DNA add-in, you can call the function from VBA via Application.Run(..).

Comment: I would also suggest Excel DNA and in particular [this post](http://mikejuniperhill.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/interfacing-c-and-vba-with-exceldna_16.html). Granted, the author uses C#, but it should be pretty much the same thing for F#.